# Dotted Line Border Around Hyperlinks in TFS in Chrome

Tags: tfs

I am getting a dotted line box border around all hyperlinks in TFS on Chrome. I don't see this anywhere other than TFS and having trouble finding out where to disable it. Does anyone know where this can be disabled in Chrome?

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Nevermind on this one. If you view your TFS profile, there's a UI Setting. Mine was set to High Contrast. Setting it to default took away the borders around all links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a UI Setting in TFS. If you edit your TFS profile, select UI Settings and change High Contrast to Default.

[image]